# tkinter - how to pack checkboxes on a new line if it would not fit in the current window size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code that makes a window with 4 checkboxes.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Resize Example")
        
        # create checkboxes
        self.checkbox_vars = [IntVar() for i in range(4)]
        self.checkbox_labels = ["Checkbox 1", "Checkbox 2", "Checkbox 3", "Checkbox 4"]
        self.checkboxes_frame = Frame(master)
        self.checkboxes_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)
        for i, label in enumerate(self.checkbox_labels):
            checkbox = Checkbutton(self.checkboxes_frame, text=label, variable=self.checkbox_vars[i])
            checkbox.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
        
        # create text input
        self.text_input = Entry(master)
        self.text_input.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.text_input.bind("<Return>", self.handle_return)
        
        # create scrolled text box
        self.scrolledtext = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(master)
        self.scrolledtext.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        
    def handle_return(self, event):
        text = self.text_input.get()
        self.text_input.delete(0, END)
        self.scrolledtext.insert(END, text + "\n")
        
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When the window is large enough to fit all checkboxes on a single line, it looks like this:
[[image]]

However, if I resize the width of the window too small, the checkboxes get clipped off:
[image]

When packing in the checkboxes, how can I check if adding in this checkbox (considering the checkbox itself and the text size) will go past the window width, and in this case start packing on a new line?
Also, if the window width is so small such that the first checkbox that is packed on a line, then the checkbox should just be clipped off because it can't fit on the line anyway.

I tried asking ChatGPT to modify its boilerplate code to fix this issue, but it was not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a borderless `Text` widget with `wrap="char"` instead of a `Frame`:

```py
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.checkboxes_frame = Text(master, wrap="char", bd=0, height=4, bg="gray95")
        self.checkboxes_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)
        for i, label in enumerate(self.checkbox_labels):
            checkbox = Checkbutton(self.checkboxes_frame, text=label,
                                       variable=self.checkbox_vars[i])
            self.checkboxes_frame.window_create("end", window=checkbox, padx=5)
        self.checkboxes_frame.config(state="disabled", cursor="arrow")
        ...
...
```

Result when the window is shrink:

[image]